# AWS Lambda schedule rate(0 minute)

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, aws-lambda, scheduler

I am [Schedule Expressions Using Rate or Cron - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html).

**The question:** Will `rate(0 minute)` scheduled lambda repeatedly start execution or `0` means never?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is already mentioned in the documentation:

> **Rate expression**
>
> ```
> rate(Value Unit)
> ```
>
> Where:
>
> *Value can be a **positive integer**.*
>
> *Unit can be minute(s), hour(s), or day(s).*

Please note the value can be a **positive** integer. and from the defnition of positive integer:

> An integer is positive if it is greater than zero and negative if it
> is less than zero.
>
> Zero is defined as neither negative nor positive.

So from these two definitions, setting scheduled rate of zero will not invoke the lambda function.

Comment: It also says: "Rate frequencies of less than one minute are not supported."